# django create profile or page for object

Tags: python, django

I have a venue object and want to have either a profile/page associated with the object which contains venue specific info like price, hours of operation and so on. Here is my venue object

```
class Venue(model.Models):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # ...
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to=...)
```

Now I have no idea where to go next with the `VenueProfile` model and the view which will bind these together this all I can think of:

```
class VenueProfile(model.Models):
    venue=models.OneToOneField(Venue, related_name='venueProfile')
    # ...
    # info i want stored about the venue
    # ...
```

Can someone please help me figure out if

1. This is the right type of model setup for a objects profile/page
2. How do I write a view for this? Connect the venue model with the profile model and render a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are taking a right approach. Usually when you want to have a decoupled entity and then later if you want to associate attributes with it (e.g. profile to a user), `OneToOneField` is very useful.

As far as connecting, since these are two separate tables, there is no really good way of merging these. However since you are using `related_name` parameter, even though models are different, you can easily access attributes of the other model by:

```
venue = Venue.objects.get(...)
venue.name             <- Venue attribute
venue.venueProfile.foo <- VenueProfile attribute
```

One down side of this approach is that there are database queries involved. To make this more efficient, you can do either one of these approaches. The first approach however is more efficient since for that, Django will use SQL join which is faster to "Python's" joins.

```
profile = VenueProfile.objects.filter(...).select_related('venue')[0]
venue = profile.venue <- no extra query
```

or this method for here Django will do the join in Python so slower:

```
venue = Venue.objects.filter(...).prefetch_related('venueProfile')[0]
```

At this point, these are just regular objects so you can easily pass them to template. The following is a simple view, urlconfig and template example:

```
def all_venues(request):
    # note that querying profiles...
    venues = VenueProfile.objects.all().select_related('venue')
    return render_to_response('template.html', {'venues':venues})

def venue(request, venue_id):
    venue = VenueProfile.objects.filter(venue__pk=venue_id).select_related('venue')
    if len(venue) == 1:
        venue = venue[0]
    else:
        raise Http404
    ...
```

urlconfig:

```
url(r'^venue/all/$', 'all_venues', name='all_venues'),
url(r'^venue/(?P<venue_id>\d+)/$', 'venue', name='venue'),
```

and template

```
{% load url from future %}
{% for venue_profile in venues %}
    {% with venue=venue_profile.venue profile=venue_profile %}
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'venue' venue_id=venue.pk %}">
                    {{ venue.name }}</a><br>
                <img href="{{ venue.image.url }}"><br>
                {{ profile.foo }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    {% endwith %}
{% empty %}
    No venues
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: ok thank you this was very helpful. So I ran a for loop to display all venue_profile.venue objects. Now I would like to include an {% url profile %} on the {{venue.name}} which will direct to the venue profile template. How would I write the view i've tried alot of things but nothing is working. Thanks

Comment: hi im sorry but this is the error i get when I did it. Reverse for 'venue' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'venue_id': ''}' not found.

Comment: I'm really sorry about this being such a django newbie, is there anything I am missing?

Comment: remove the `{% url ... %}` and instead put there `{{venue.pk}}`. It should put an integer value. Does it?

Comment: ok that part where you did {% for venue_profile in venues %}
    {% with venue=venue_profile.venue profile=venue_profile %}

Comment: sorry i did {% for v in venues %}
  {% with ven=v.venue profile=v %} so when i do {{ven.pk}} yes I see a integar

Comment: so in the url i did {% url 'venue' ven_pk=ven_id %} but still noreverse match. and not only that, I was using django generic views to add/delete objects which was working perfectly fine and now there is also a no reverse match on those urls also

Comment: paste somewhere your view and the template to something like pastebin

Comment: `{% url 'venue' ven_id=ven_pk %}` is incorrect. change that to `{% url 'venue' ven_id=ven.pk %}`. you were trying to reference variable which is not there which was outputting empty string, hence url reverse failure.

Comment: once again im sorry but i feel like were close, i got this.Reverse for 'venue' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'ven_id': 1}' not found.

Comment: in the future, please try to copy code exactly as it is posted. you changed all the variables, hence these conflicts happen... `{% url 'venue' venue_id=ven.pk %}` should work.

Comment: so sorry and yes that did clear it up but now i get this. 'VenueProfile' object has no attribute 'select_related'.....from venue= get_object_or_404(VenueProfile,      venue__pk=venue_id).select_related('venue')

Comment: once again i feel like were so close,I know your probably frustrated dealing with a newbie like me, but please help me finish this out. Thanks

Comment: oh, right. forgot about about that. `select_related` is only applicable to querysets. `get_object_or_404` returns an object, so you cannot apply that method there. I updated the answer

Comment: YES YES AND MORE YES. THANK YOU SO MUCH I WISH I COULD TREAT YOU TO DINNER OR SOMETHING LIKE THAT, ONCE AGAIN THANKS. Also would you like to help me on parts of my project? I am looking to contract some of it out. If so direct me somewhere you would like to chat maybe skype or email. Thanks